# Volume rendering in WebGL

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have:

1. a 3D array containing a 3d dataset to be displayed
2. a 4x4 matrix which defines spacing/scaling/orientation of the volume to be displayed
3. a opacity transfer function
4. a color transfer function

I would like to use ThreeJS to do volume rendering (MIP, RayCasting, etc.) of this data. What WebGL shaders must be created to fulfil the task? References on existing implementations are welcome, but only as a supplement for your answer.

Should I work directly at the shader level or in javascript?

Comment: There is the marching cubes example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_marchingcubes

Comment: mrdoob also linked an example he did in 2012 in a gihub issue : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1821

Answer (score 1):

[WAVE Client Renderer](https://github.com/kit-ipe/WAVE-Client-Renderer) is a Three.js-based library for Volume Rendering via Ray Casting.

GPU accelerated Volume Ray Casting is usually implemented multi-pass rendering.

The first pass of shaders is very simple. It draws to the texture coordinates (at object coordinates) of position their the rays hit the back side of cube.

You can find examples of GLSL shaders, with ejs templet below.

**firstPass.frag**

```
precision mediump int; 

precision mediump float; 



varying vec4 backColor; 



void main(void) 

{ 

    gl_FragColor = backColor; 

}
```

**firstPass.vert**

```
precision mediump int; 

precision mediump float; 



attribute vec4 vertColor; 



varying vec4 backColor; 

varying vec4 pos; 



void main(void) 

{ 

    backColor = vertColor; 



    pos = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0); 

    gl_Position = pos; 

}
```

The second pass performs an actual sampling of the data and visualization of final image.

**secondPass.vert**

```
precision mediump int; 

precision mediump float; 



attribute vec4 vertColor; 



varying vec4 backColor; 

varying vec4 pos; 



void main(void) 

{ 

    backColor = vertColor; 



    pos = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0); 

    gl_Position = pos; 

}
```

**secondPass.frag**

```
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH 

 // highp is supported 

 precision highp int; 

 precision highp float; 

#else 

 // high is not supported 

 precision mediump int; 

 precision mediump float; 

#endif 



varying vec4 frontColor; 

varying vec4 pos; 



uniform sampler2D uBackCoord; 

uniform sampler2D uTransferFunction;

uniform sampler2D uSliceMaps[<%= maxTexturesNumber %>];



uniform float uNumberOfSlices; 

uniform float uMinGrayVal; 

uniform float uMaxGrayVal; 

uniform float uOpacityVal; 

uniform float uColorVal; 

uniform float uAbsorptionModeIndex;

uniform float uSlicesOverX; 

uniform float uSlicesOverY; 

uniform float uSteps; 

// uniform int uAvailable_textures_number;



//Acts like a texture3D using Z slices and trilinear filtering. 

float getVolumeValue(vec3 volpos)

{

    float s1Original, s2Original, s1, s2; 

    float dx1, dy1; 

    // float dx2, dy2; 

    // float value; 



    vec2 texpos1,texpos2; 



    float slicesPerSprite = uSlicesOverX * uSlicesOverY; 



    s1Original = floor(volpos.z*uNumberOfSlices); 

    // s2Original = min(s1Original + 1.0, uNumberOfSlices);



    int tex1Index = int(floor(s1Original / slicesPerSprite));

    // int tex2Index = int(floor(s2Original / slicesPerSprite));



    s1 = mod(s1Original, slicesPerSprite);

    // s2 = mod(s2Original, slicesPerSprite);



    dx1 = fract(s1/uSlicesOverX);

    dy1 = floor(s1/uSlicesOverY)/uSlicesOverY;



    // dx2 = fract(s2/uSlicesOverX);

    // dy2 = floor(s2/uSlicesOverY)/uSlicesOverY;



    texpos1.x = dx1+(volpos.x/uSlicesOverX);

    texpos1.y = dy1+(volpos.y/uSlicesOverY);



    // texpos2.x = dx2+(volpos.x/uSlicesOverX);

    // texpos2.y = dy2+(volpos.y/uSlicesOverY);



    float value1 = 0.0, value2 = 0.0; 

    // bool value1Set = false, value2Set = false;



    // int numberOfSlicemaps = int( ceil(uNumberOfSlices / (uSlicesOverX * uSlicesOverY)) );



    <% for(var i=0; i < maxTexturesNumber; i++) { %>

        if( tex1Index == <%=i%> )

        {

            value1 = texture2D(uSliceMaps[<%=i%>],texpos1).x;

        }



        <% if( i < maxTexturesNumber-1 ) { %>

            else

        <% } %>

    <% } %>



    return value1;



    // for (int x = 0; x < gl_MaxTextureImageUnits-2; x++)

    // {

    //     if(x == numberOfSlicemaps)

    //     {

    //         break;

    //     }



    //     if(x == tex1Index) { 

    //         value1 = texture2D(uSliceMaps[x],texpos1).x; 

    //         value1Set = true; 

    //     } 



    //     if(x == tex2Index) { 

    //         value2 = texture2D(uSliceMaps[x],texpos2).x; 

    //         value2Set = true; 

    //     } 



    //     if(value1Set && value2Set) { 

    //         break; 

    //     } 



    // } 



    // return mix(value1, value2, fract(volpos.z*uNumberOfSlices)); 



} 



void main(void)

{

 vec2 texC = ((pos.xy/pos.w) + 1.0) / 2.0; 



 vec4 backColor = texture2D(uBackCoord,texC); 



 vec3 dir = backColor.rgb - frontColor.rgb; 

 //dir /= length(dir); 



 vec4 vpos = frontColor; 



//      vec3 Step = dir/uSteps; 

 vec3 Step = dir/uSteps; 



 vec4 accum = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0); 

 vec4 sample = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

 vec4 colorValue = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0); 

 float biggest_gray_value = 0.0; 



 float opacityFactor = uOpacityVal; 

 float lightFactor = uColorVal; 



 // const 4095 - just example of big number 

 // It because expression i > uSteps impossible 

 for(float i = 0.0; i < 4095.0; i+=1.0) 

 { 

 // It because expression i > uSteps impossible 

     if(i == uSteps) { 

         break; 

     } 



     float gray_val = getVolumeValue(vpos.xyz); 



     if(gray_val < uMinGrayVal || gray_val > uMaxGrayVal) { 

         colorValue = vec4(0.0); 

     } else { 

         if(biggest_gray_value < gray_val) { 

            biggest_gray_value = gray_val;

         } 



         if(uAbsorptionModeIndex == 0.0) 

         { 

             vec2 tf_pos; 

             tf_pos.x = (gray_val - uMinGrayVal) / (uMaxGrayVal - uMinGrayVal); 

             tf_pos.y = 0.5; 



             colorValue = texture2D(uTransferFunction,tf_pos);

             //colorValue = vec4(tf_pos.x, tf_pos.x, tf_pos.x, 1.0); 



             sample.a = colorValue.a * opacityFactor; 

             sample.rgb = colorValue.rgb * uColorVal; 

             accum += sample; 



             if(accum.a>=1.0) 

                break; 



         } 



         if(uAbsorptionModeIndex == 1.0) 

         { 

             vec2 tf_pos; 

             tf_pos.x = (gray_val - uMinGrayVal) / (uMaxGrayVal - uMinGrayVal); 

             tf_pos.y = 0.5; 



             colorValue = texture2D(uTransferFunction,tf_pos);

             //colorValue = vec4(tf_pos.x, tf_pos.x, tf_pos.x, 1.0); 



             sample.a = colorValue.a * opacityFactor * (1.0 / uSteps); 

             sample.rgb = (1.0 - accum.a) * colorValue.rgb * sample.a * lightFactor; 

             accum += sample; 



             if(accum.a>=1.0) 

                break; 



         } 



         if(uAbsorptionModeIndex == 2.0) 

         { 

             vec2 tf_pos; 

             tf_pos.x = (biggest_gray_value - uMinGrayVal) / (uMaxGrayVal - uMinGrayVal); 

             tf_pos.y = 0.5; 



             colorValue = texture2D(uTransferFunction,tf_pos);

             //colorValue = vec4(tf_pos.x, tf_pos.x, tf_pos.x, 1.0); 

             sample.a = colorValue.a * opacityFactor; 

             sample.rgb = colorValue.rgb * uColorVal; 



             accum = sample; 



         } 



     } 



     //advance the current position 

     vpos.xyz += Step; 



     //break if the position is greater than <1, 1, 1> 

     if(vpos.x > 1.0 || vpos.y > 1.0 || vpos.z > 1.0 || vpos.x < 0.0 || vpos.y < 0.0 || vpos.z < 0.0) 

     { 

         break; 

     } 



 } 



 gl_FragColor = accum; 



}
```

Comment: is it better now?